# Conditional modal with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to know how to implement a route with React Router that either opens as a modal or a full page.

Given a list of items, when users click on an item, I would like to open a modal.
However, when users visit the item's url directly, I would like to render a full page.

An example of this behavior can be seen on https://producthunt.com/.

When users visits a url for an item from the main page, the page is shown as a modal. However, when users go directly to the item's url, it's a full page.

I am doing server side rendering. Any ideas on where to begin?

### Edit

If anyone is solving a similar problem, see this official example: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/pinterest

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am trying to follow the pinterest example but in my case, the router always transitions to the url (and loses the background page). In the ProductHunt/Pinterest cases, they go from clicking on a link in Component's preview state to go to the component's full state in the modal - not sure if that is adding additional complication causing the issue I mentioned..

Comment: Yes. I followed the pinterest example. My solution is in production now. This is an example: https://remotebase.io. Regarding losing the background page, are  you saving the old children and rendering the old children in the background in case the new route is modal? See https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/pinterest/app.js#L46 and https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/pinterest/app.js#L64-L67. If modal, you should render the old children in the background.

Comment: Is there a better way than saving the children and rendering them again? It doesn't seem performant or clean. Like in the case of Pinterest or Product Hunt, that would mean re-rendering the entire feed?

Comment: Not sure if the example is re-rendering the entire feed. But yeah I've noticed that in my development environment, opening a modal is kind of slow. In production, it is usable.

Comment: Thanks! One final question - did you attempt building the next/previous that ProductHunt/Pinterest has? It seems like the entire background would be re-rendered? And in that case, did you pass all the items through the modal? Or had custom logic when next/prev is entered and the router state is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use component live cycle method componentWillReceiveProps to find out if router has locationBeforeTransitions prop set to some value.

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
  if (this.props.router.locationBeforeTransitions === null) {
    // initial display should render page
  }

  // transition display should render modal
}
```

Best practice is to use wrapper for this decision and do not overcomplicate components by giving them knowledge of the router props.

I am using it this way and it works.

```
"react-router": "^2.3.0",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.2",
```

Comment: From your experience, do search engines see the full page or modals? My guess is that search engines cURLs the URL so they will see the full page but I am not too sure.

Comment: Search engines do not run client javascript. So you can try that by running curl or use google webmaster tools to retrieve it.